# onSelect event datepicker triggers change of minTime value in timepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, timepicker

When "today" is selected in datepicker, the `minTime` of timepicker is = current time, and if the select date is not today, the `minTime` of timepicker is = `"12:00am"`. But the `minTime` value (below) is never being triggered (I guess) when I tried to select different date. The `console.log()` shows the if statement is working fine thou.

```js
var selection = jQuery("input#ezfc_element-15-child.ezfc-element-timepicker").data("settings");
var today = localdate.toLocaleDateString("en-US");
setTimeout(function(){
    jQuery( ".ezfc-element-datepicker" ).datepicker({
        minDate: new Date(today),
        defaultDate: new Date(today),
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
            var ds_milliseconds = Date.parse(dateText);
            var t_milliseconds = Date.parse(today);
            if (t_milliseconds == ds_milliseconds) {
                selection['minTime'] = minTime;
                console.log ("minTime");
            } else { 
                selection['minTime'] = "12:00am" ;
                console.log("12:00am");
            }
        }
     });

 }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried opening your browser console, selection is not a valid usage, replace your if else section with below code

```
if (t_milliseconds == ds_milliseconds) {
    $(this).datepicker('option', 'minTime', minTime);
    console.log ("minTime");
} else { 
    $(this).datepicker('option', 'minTime', "12:00am");
    console.log("12:00am");
}
```

Comment: but it is `$(."input#ezfc_element-15-child.ezfc-element-timepicker").timepicker` not `$(."input#ezfc_element-15-child.ezfc-element-timepicker").datepicker`, otherwise it works well. May I ask why it needs 'option' ? what does it do and what is the difference from without having the 'option' in it? I am pretty new to this. Please kindly explain this to me, thanks

Comment: You have .datepicker in your code, and about why you need 'option' refer http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate